# Daily scheduled tasks with schtasks command Next Run issue

Tags: windows, cmd, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have been trying to set up a scheduled task to run every morning but I can't quite find the best way to do it with schtasks. It is not running as expected, so far I've tried:

```
schtasks /Create /tn "MyTask" /sc DAILY /mo 1 /st 07:00:00 /et 08:00:00 /sd 04-01-2017 /ru user /rp "password" /tr "C:\my.exe /arg"
```

For this one if the date is in the past there is no Next Run Date and it won't be triggered

```
schtasks /Create /tn "MyTask" /sc DAILY /mo 1 /st 07:00:00 /et 08:00:00 /sd $nextdaydate /ru user /rp "password" /tr "C:\my.exe /arg"
```

With this I have the Next Run Date set up the next day at 7am, it runs at 7am and then the next run date becomes N.A. and the task runs every 10 minutes.

I am thinking to use an HOURLY one instead and run every 24 hours but wanted to know if people had the same issue and if they fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using `/et`. If you look at `schtasks /create /?` it tells you `/ri` defaults to every 10mins if `/et` is used.

Your options will be to either give the interval as 24 hours, or remove the switch.

If this isn't an option, maybe schedule another task to kill it an hour later?

Comment: Thank you, I thought I could use /et to force the task to stop if it is still running after 1 hour. I don't really need it and it is working without. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

For the record I decided to use Powershell:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'myApp.exe' -Argument 'arg'
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 07:00:00
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "TaskName" -Description "It works" -User user -Password "password"
```